# Click-to-Drag Screenshot missing in 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-screenshot

Previously (21.10 and earlier) there were keyboard shortcuts available to take a click-and-drag screenshot.

It appears as though that is no longer possible in 22.04. The closest option is now "take screenshot interactively" but this forces you do draw/manually shape the four corners, one at a time and is quite a bit slower.

Am I missing something obvious? Is this just a QA/Regression miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

If you click "outside" of the pre-drawn screenshot box, it allows you to click & drag like the legacy feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Screenshot` Tool in 22.04 LTS

If you select `Selection` and then <kbd>Take Screenshot</kbd> you will be presented with the cross hairs which you can then use to make your selection as it was before.

If not already installed on your system, you can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like screenshot with selection that also may be dragged

is possible using: <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>

instead of (Ubunut before `22.04`): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>

[image]